# What are options for TCL GUI to look "native" on windows?

Tags: c, windows, api, tcl, tk-toolkit

So I found Tk alike [GNOCL](http://wiki.tcl.tk/5151) for linux Gtk. I wonder if there is any alike Tk libraries using windows native buttons and other components for tcl? (the more its api looks like Tk the better.) 
Is there any su

Comment: What happened to the rest of your question?

Comment: How is this question substantively different from [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520587/why-tk-on-windows-7-does-not-look-any-way-native)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tk 8.5 has native look & feel support through the [Tile](http://tktable.sourceforge.net/tile/) theme engine, renamed [Ttk](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_intro.htm). If you're not using very exotic Tk features, it should be possible to replace Tk with Ttk in your application and get native looks, keyboard bindings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The [Tile](http://wiki.tcl.tk/11075) theming engine should already (as of v.8.5a6) be part of Tk, known as [Ttk](http://wiki.tcl.tk/14796) , and should help make Tk look more native on Windows platforms.